# Link stays on its hover property when target="_blank"

Tags: html, css

Whenever I set a link to open up into a new window and return to the previous one the hover properties set for it stick but when I mouse back in to the window it changes back to normal. How can I fix this without using Javascript?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a:link, a:visited, a:active {color: blue;}

a:hover {color: red;}
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/5EXFB/

Comment: Did you happen to get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a link styled as a button that was keeping its hover font color when the click action was to open a new window. The issue is that the link retains focus (which holds the hover style) until you click on something else, which is apparently an accessibility thing. The workaround I came up with is to add a :focus style and a :focus:hover style to mimic the regular a and a:hover styles.

```
a, a:focus { color: blue }
a:hover, a:focus:hover { color: white }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** It doesn't look like there is a way to do it in Chrome.  Even setting focus to another element behind the scenes doesn't

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    a:link {color: blue;}
    a:hover {color: red; background-color:yellow}
    a:active {color: red;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<input type='text'>Click this: </input>
<a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">yahoo</a>
<script>
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('input').focus();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** My code below doesn't work in IE or Chrome. In IE, when you switch back to the window, the active focus is already gone and in Chrome the mouseover definitely removes the active focus.  In fact, I think the active focus is already gone once the target window opens, it is just that IE repaints immediately and Chrome repaints later.

=======================

Move the :active to be the same as the :hover:

```
a:link, a:visited, {color: blue;}

a:hover, a:active {color: red;}
```

That should work in the situation you describe which is to mouseover the window again.  If, however, you click in the window, the link will no longer be the active element, so the style will be lost as well.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. What I'm trying to avoid is the link maintaining the hover property after it gets clicked. So right after I click the link I want it to revert to its original style(s).

Comment: See my update. Are you testing with Chrome then?  I suspect you'll need some javascript

Comment: Yes, I'm in Chrome. Is there a thread already out there that addresses this bug fix using JS?

Comment: You'll have to keep digging.  My ideas have come up short.

Comment: it's been a month, just checking to see if there has been any progress on this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. :visited worked for me while :focus did not. With visited, it selects the link that has already been visited by the current browser. Focus is for those who used keyboard navigation to get to the link. :focus will select links that are the current focus of the keyboard.

```
&:visited { color: $color--tory-blue;       
background-color: $color--white;}

&:hover{color: $color--white;       
background-color: $color--tory-blue;}
```