# CSS li a:visited overriding hover state on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, hover, desktop, visited

I'm having trouble with visited links and hover states. The social media icons at the bottom of my site have a:list hover state set to a red colour. After the user visits the link, it remains white. On mobile devices as hover states aren't really a thing, there is no red colour. However, when clicking one of the social icons, it remains red. I tried setting the visited colour to white which removes the icon remaining red problem. However, going back to desktop devices means the hover state stops working.

This is the code:

```
footer li a:hover {
color: #e91d26;
}

footer li a:active {
color: #fff;
}

footer li a:link {
color: #fff;
}

footer li a:visited {
color: #fff;
}
```

Attached is an image showing the problem on mobile devices with footer li a visited commented out.

[a:visited white commented out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8dJy.png)

Comment: Move your `footer li a:hover` declaration to the bottom, below `:visited`.

Comment: [How To Remember The Order of Selectors: LOVE and HATE](https://css-tricks.com/remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate)

Comment: I see you're avoiding adding any extra class, but I don't think it would hurt adding something like a .visitedLi to the one already visited, and might help your cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply a [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem.

To fix this, simply move your `footer li a:hover` declaration to the bottom, below `footer li a:visited`.

like this:

```
footer li a:active {
    color: #fff;
}

footer li a:link {
    color: #fff;
}

footer li a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

/* Move : hover down here.. */
footer li a:hover {
    color: #e91d26;
}
```

Or you could add `!important` to the `color` property in your `:hover` declaration, but this is more of a hack and not suggested..

```
/* not suggested... but would work */

footer li a:hover {
    color: #e91d26; !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that sorts the hovering state remaining red, but on mobile devices after you hit one of the icons then go back to the site, it remains red. I'd like it to go back to white or remain white if you see what I mean: https://hopeful-goldberg-c5d951.netlify.com/

Comment: What do you mean, "it remains red?"  It remains red even if you are not hovering over it?

Comment: Sorry poor choice of words. Hover state works fine. No hover on mobile. Clicking (touching) one of the icons opens the app/site. Go back to the main website. Look at the social icon you clicked (touched) and it's red. I want it to be white. Sorry if I'm not being clear!

Comment: Ohhh... I see what you mean..  I believe this is a feature of the browser..  for accessibilitiy purposes.  You can check out another SO post about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495551/link-stays-on-its-hover-property-when-target-blank

Comment: @SimonLowes , if you feel I answered your question, would you mind selecting it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495551/link-stays-on-its-hover-property-when-target-blank

Comment: Thank you, Bryan.